# I Cant bypass data-validation using formvalidator platform

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-form-validator

I cant disable data-validation using formvalidator. I tried novalidate of html5 but its not working.

Here's my code. Please assume that i have a correct form tag pointing to save the textbox1 even if it has no value.

**PHP**

```
<input name="textbox1" data-validation="alphanumeric" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name=save" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="save_to_draft" value="Save to Draft" />
```

---

Goal: I want to save textbox1 even its value is nothing.
I don't know to disable data-validations in formvalidator platform. You can check the formvalidator site [here](http://formvalidator.net).

Sorry for my bad english. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. I'm not sure if this is the best answer but i'd like to share it.

**The code**

```
<input name="textbox1" data-validation="alphanumeric" type="text"/>
<input name="textbox2" data-validation="alphanumeric" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name=save" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="save_to_draft" value="Save to Draft" />
```

**The fix**

```
add class to input tag.
```

**PHP**

```
<input name="textbox1"  class="toggle_validation" data-validation="alphanumeric" type="text"/> 
<input name="textbox2"  class="toggle_validation" data-validation="alphanumeric" type="text"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        /*remove restriction for input tag*/
        $("#save_to_draft").click(function()
        {
            $(".toggle_validation").each(function()
            {       
                $(this).attr("data-validation-optional","true");   
            });
        });
        /*add restriction for input tag*/
        $("#save").click(function()
        { 
            $(".toggle_validation").each(function()
            {      
                $(this).removeAttr("data-validation-optional"); 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.